# Using class attribute in method definition as argument?

Tags: python, method-parameters, class-attribute

I have the following code :

```
class Blah:
  ABC, DEF = range(2)

  def meth(self, arg=Blah.ABC):
     .....
```

Blah.ABC works inside the method or any place outside , the only place it does not work is in the method definition !!!

Any way to resolve this ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the class name Blah yet since it hasn't finished being constructed.  But you can directly access the class member ABC without prefacing it with the class:

```
class Blah:
    ABC, DEF = range(2)

    def meth(self, arg=ABC):
        print arg

Blah().meth()
# it prints '0'
```

It also works using 'new' style class definition, eg:

```
class Blah(object):
    ABC, DEF = range(2)
```

By the time I really got into python, new style classes were the norm, and they are much more like other OO languages.. so that's all I use.  Not sure what the advantages are (if any) to sticking with the old way.. but it seems deprecated, so I would say that unless there's a reason I would use the new style.  Perhaps someone else can comment on this.

Comment: `class Blah:` defines an "only-style" class in Python 3, where you no longer have to explicitly inherit from `object`.